# Getting error status on OpenShift for pod

Tags: deployment, openshift

New to using OpenShift. I have a nodeJS app that I want to deploy. The files are in github and structure is as below: [image]

My package.json is like so (I've omitted the dependencies, author and description parts):

```
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
```

I made sure it runs on my local. The build on Openshift was successful, however the pod failed with the error status: CrashLoopBackoff. In the logs it says it can't find the `app.js` file but it's clearly there unless my eyes deceive me...I've attached the log below

[image]

Not sure what else that might be important to include so apologies if I'm missing some crucial information on here.

Comment: try `"main": "App.js",`

Comment: Did that, still got an error. I just realised it made 3 pods (which i probably didn't notice before) - <projectname>-1-deploy , <projectname>-1-build, and <projectname>-1-6gj94. The 'deploy' one says 'Running' and ready, 'build' says 'Complete', but the '6gj94' says "Error" which is the same one as above.

Comment: Nevermind it got fixed, was definately due to the capital naming! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed error, was due to the capital 'A' in App.js, so changed to `node App.js` and main as `App.js`